# How to give path for python file from directory

Tags: python, path, robotframework

I had python file tests.py in project folder and I could call the methods as follows:

```
Library  tests.Tests
```

But I moved tests.py to folder python_tests in same project folder but I can't seem to get path right.
I tried below things

```
Library  python_tests/tests.Tests
Library  /python_tests/tests.Tests
Library  /home/robot_project/python_tests/tests.Tests
Library  home/robot_project/python_tests/tests.Tests
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either use a pathname (absolute,  or relative to the test), or a module name for a module on your path, but you can't mix the two techniques.

- If `python_tests` is a package that is on your PYTHONPATH, `python_tests.tests.Tests` should work.
- If you put the path to `python_tests` in your PYTHONPATH, `tests.Tests` should work.
- If python_tests is not a package, `python_tests/tests/Tests.py` should work.

This is all covered in the robot framework user guide, in the section titled [Specifying library to import](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-library-to-import). Here are a couple of exerpts:

> The most common way to specify a test library to import is using its
>   name.... In these cases Robot Framework tries to find the class or
>   module implementing the library from the module search path. Libraries
>   that are installed somehow ought to be in the module search path
>   automatically, but with other libraries the search path may need to be
>   configured separately.

...

> Another mechanism for specifying the library to import is using a path
>   to it in the file system. This path is considered relative to the
>   directory where current test data file is situated ... The main
>   benefit of this approach is that there is no need to configure the
>   module search path.